# Stove turns on some of my power (partial power outage)

Tags: electrical, stove

I was cooking, having all the ACs on and washing clothes and someone of the power in my house turned off and hasn’t turned on. But when I turn on the stove some lights turn back on. Is this bad and how can I fix this?

Comment: You lost a phase (hot wire) to your house. 95% of the time it's your power company's pole line to your house, which they fix for free.  Contact the power company immediately and report an outage. Tell them half your lights and sockets are out and your oven doesn't work (it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

You have an open phase. Since the range turns on the other lights it is in the feed to the breaker box where these all connect. In days past it was usually one of the main cartridge fuses in the main fuse block. If you have fuses before your breaker check them. Try turning the main off and on several times and see if that clears the problem. If not it is probably a bad feed from your power provider. You need to get it fixed as about 1/2 of your home is not working or under low voltage conditions where the electric dryer etc do not work very well if at all.

Comment: If a fuse is open how would the power return? Are you stating a 120 and 240v light are connected ? I hope you can explain tired of down votes from internet only electricians

Comment: Yes, power from the good phase will go through say a dryer heating element, range, etc and dump power into the other phase, it acts like a resistor. You will not get 220V between phases but ~120 to ground from each. The 220V unit must be connect to both phases and on for this to happen. This will happen with any 220V loads that are connected between phase. You could get 120V but probably much less on the bad phase depending on the 220V load. Good Luck! Sorry I am not an internet electrician, I worked as a journeyman in the 60 and 70's and then went into electronics, best move I ever made.